# Get all combinations of a binary string with bit flips at specific indices (Python)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, binary, combinations

I have a binary string. I have a list of bit indices to flip. How can I generate all possible combinations of binary strings with flips at those specific indices? The output list should contain 2^n unique elements where n is the length of the indices list. I believe itertools.product() could be used here, but I can't figure out how to line up all the parameters, especially since the length of the indices list is variable.

Example:

```
binaryString = "0000000000"
indicesToFlip = [0,1,9]

outputCombinations = magic()

print(outputCombinations)

["0000000000",
 "1000000000",
 "0100000000",
 "1100000000",
 "0000000001",
 "0100000001",
 "1000000001",
 "1100000001"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import combinations

binaryString = "0000000000"
indicesToFlip = [0, 1, 9]

out = []
for i in range(len(indicesToFlip) + 1):
    for c in combinations(indicesToFlip, i):
        out.append(
            "".join(
                ("1" if ch == "0" else "0") if i in c else ch
                for i, ch in enumerate(binaryString)
            )
        )

print(*out, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
0000000000
1000000000
0100000000
0000000001
1100000000
1000000001
0100000001
1100000001
```

Comment: The recursion solution looks cool too, but this easier to read. I ended up writing my own solution that used itertools.product() but this is cleaner.

Comment: To anyone who cares, you should modify this code to check if the new binary string is in `out` before appending it, because this code as is will produce duplicates if someone puts duplicate indices in `indicesToFlip`, such as `indicesToFlip = [0,1,9,0]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate all binary representations with the number of binary digits that corresponds to the number of indices (like 000, 001, 010, 011, ...) and then use a regular expression replacement that injects those digits in the larger binary string.

```
import re
    
def combis(binaryString, indicesToFlip):
    # Prepare the regex...
    n = len(indicesToFlip)
    regex = re.compile("(.)" * n)
    # ... and the replacement pattern
    mask = list(binaryString)
    for i, idx in enumerate(indicesToFlip):
        mask[idx] = rf"\g<{i+1}>"
    replacer = "".join(mask)
    # Apply that transformation to each number in the range [0..2^n)
    return [regex.sub(replacer, f"{num:>0{n}b}") for num in range(1 << n)]

binaryString = "0000000000"
indicesToFlip = [0,1,9]
print(combis(binaryString, indicesToFlip))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's answer that cycles through the all combinations of indices to toggle using `itertools` but here's a recursive implementation of your `magic()` function.

```
def magic(S, indices):
    L = list(S) # convert to list of binary characters for mutation
    def recurse(L, indices, curr):
        if curr == len(indices): # done
            return [''.join(L)]  # return as list in order to accumulate results
            
        res = recurse(L, indices, curr + 1)          # do not flip
        og = L[indices[curr]]
        L[indices[curr]] = '1' if og == '0' else '0' # change
        res += recurse(L, indices, curr + 1)         # re-run, effectively doing a flip
        L[indices[curr]] = og                        # revert
        return res
        
    return recurse(L, list(reversed(indices)), 0)    # reversed input indices to get desired order
    
for elm in magic("0" * 10, [0, 1, 9]): # your test case
    print(elm)
```

Prints:

```
0000000000
1000000000
0100000000
1100000000
0000000001
1000000001
0100000001
1100000001
```